# Calling any of AccountManager getAccounts makes my application stop

Tags: java, android

This code reproduces the problem, nothing more. Just a single activity and creating an instance of `AccountManger` then calling `getAccounts()` and it never reaches the `for (...` line.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accounts = manager.getAccounts();
        for (int index = 0 ; index < accounts.length ; ++index)
            Log.i("RumbAPK", accounts[index].name);
    }
}
```

All I want to do is to be able to list current accounts and check whether or not it's authenticated, to use it as an authentication system for my app.

**Edit**:

As requested by @[CommonsWave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976345/calling-any-of-accountmanager-getaccounts-makes-my-application-stop#comment51859171_31976345) and of course because it has to be useful.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10085 lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1428)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1382)
    at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getAccountsAsUser(IAccountManager.java:541)
    at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByTypeAsUser(AccountManager.java:414)
    at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountManager.java:408)
    at com.har.innovation.and.technology.rumbapk.GoogleLoginManager.authenticate(GoogleLoginManager.java:31)
    at com.har.innovation.and.technology.rumbapk.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:132)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4220)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17510)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check LogCat for the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Do you have the permission android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the stack trace I'm quite sure you are missing the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Please add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

More [Informations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) about the permissions system on android.

Comment: From the comments I already figured it out, and yes you are completely right. And it's very helpful to post the single line about hot to make the application request permission. You saved me a lot of time and research, thank you.

Comment: @iharob I was not downvoting your question. It was perfectly valid for me.

Comment: Yes, don't worry. It's very common on stack overflow to downvote questions for no reason. I consider myself a good c programmer and this is my first android application. I don't like helper tools because they confuse me, I like stuff to be as simple as possible and since I am not using any tool to tell me about permissions, I didn't even think of it. But I did read about the fact that I needed permission, just assumed that I had it. I am sure that in a short time I will be a good android programmer as well.

Comment: @iharob Using a good ide, like Android Studio, is a big help, especially for layouts (regenerating the constants for R), permissions (Android Studio will warn you about missing ones), ... Imho the whole native Android development is wrapped around a good ide. Unfortunately, if there are bugs in the ide, it will complicate your work much more than if you use separated tools: I spend hours with unit tests (I was not able to run them). After an upgrade from AS 1.2 to 1.3, test are suddenly running. I'm also not yet convinced about the programming model compared to cordova with html5/js.

Comment: I tried, I failed at getting used to it. It's just so much when all you really need is a text editor. But the main reason I discarded Android Studio for is Gradle, it was running all the time and taking +800M RAM. My machine only has 4G and for me 800M is a lot, it left my computer unusable since it started using swap and writing to the disk is very slow as you know, so the whole system was very very slow.

Comment: I was able to list the accounts now, and I know that it will be a little harder to work like this (I am using eclipse) it helps me a lot but it just didn't warn about permissions. I am happy with eclipse because even if it uses a lot of memory too, it's not as much as Android Studio, my editor with all the coding aids and stuff is very responsive and I love it.

Comment: What about using Intellij? I recomienda @iharob. Regards

Comment: @MaxPinto Intellij *is* Android Studio. They have an arrangement with google and produce this ide exclusively and free for Android development (before that, Eclipse was the official ide)